# sstream class to read integers from character array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, iostream, stringstream

I have not seen any proper application of utilizing stringstream to read in a list of integers from a character array.

Elements should be input as space delimited string/(char array) on one line and sstream class utilized to perform requisite transformation.

This should be done without utilizing vector or any other additional STL container (only std::string and char array), the length of resulting array of integers should be stored in a variable.

What is the most efficient way of preforming such an operation?

Comment: There's literally hundreds of examples of using `stringstream` to read integers from a string. Or are you wanting to implement your own `stringstream`?

Comment: Could you provide a working example of a user provided string being read and converted to integer array via stringstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume I understand what you're meaning, then

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string apples;
    std::getline( std::cin, apples );

    std::istringstream iss( apples );

    std::vector<int> vec;
    int val;

    while ( iss >> val ) {
        vec.push_back( val );
    }

    for ( int i : vec ) {
        std::cout << i << ',';
    }
}
```

Comment: Without using a vector, store the input into integer array (pointer).

Comment: It's simple to convert from an existing `vector` to an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is more along the lines of what I was getting at.

```
int* theheap = new int[10];
std::string num;
int val = 0;
int size = 0;
std::cout << "Enter the elements of heap" << std::endl;
std::getline( std::cin, num );
std::istringstream iss(num);    
while ( iss >> val ) {
   if (val != ' '){
      theheap[size] = val;
      ++size;
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to compare against `' '`, in fact, that would make it ignore the number 32. Since `iss >> val` reads integers already, and skips the spaces.